# How to change color of cell based on value in datatable

Tags: datatables

I have a table based on Datatable plugin and json,I need to change the color of the last cell based on value,for example for lower value color will be green,for medium orange,for higher it will be red.I tried but its not working. Can anyone please help me on it.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="script.js"></script>
<div id="div">
<div>
 <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>            
                <th>name</th>
                <th>stargazerscount</th>
                <th>forkscount</th>
                <th>description</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>          
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>  
</div>
```

### script.js

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 3,
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      if (( cellData > 3 ) && ( cellData < 10 )){
        $(td).css('color', 'green')
      }
      else
           if (( cellData > 11 ) && ( cellData < 45 )){
        $(td).css('color', 'orange')
      }
      else
           if (( cellData > 45 ) && ( cellData < 100 )){
        $(td).css('color', 'red')
      }
    }
  } ],

language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
    },
 "ajax": {
             "type"   : "POST",
            "url": "http://localhost/datatables/colorchange/1.json",
             "dataSrc": function (json) {
      var return_data = new Array();
      for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){

        return_data.push({

         'name': json[i].name,
          'stargazerscount'  : '<span onclick="f()">'+json[i].stargazerscount+'</span>',
           'forkscount'  : json[i].forkscount,
          'description' : json[i].description,

        })

      }
      return return_data;
             }
    },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "stargazerscount" },
            { "data": "forkscount" },
            { "data": "description" }

        ]

}); 
});
```

### 1.json

```
[{
            "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "5"
        },
        {
             "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "4"
        },
        {
              "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "15.5"
        },
        {
              "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "25.5"
        },
        {
              "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "45.5"
        },
        {
              "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "25.5"
        },
        {
              "name": "event 1",
            "stargazerscount": "program 1",
            "forkscount": "3",
            "description": "75.5"
        }


    ]
```

Comment: I tried its not working

Comment: its working now I removed span from that row